# tradingview PineScript v2 ->v3~ v5 Chart results are different

Tags: pine-script

tradingview PineScript  v2 ->v3~ v5  Chart results are different.

Is it possible to do the same with the chart result?

Image result is attached :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Cki.png)

```
//@version=2
 

strategy("Strategy",shorttitle="Strategy  ",overlay=true,default_qty_value=1000,initial_capital=1000,currency=currency.USD)

res1   = input(title="Time frame (Minutes. Not lower than chart)", type=string, defval="300")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
fama = input(16,"Heikin Ashi EMA Period")
test = input(0,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")


ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift])

//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],fama)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=lime,linewidth=2,style=line)
```

```
//@version=5 

strategy(title='Strategy  ', shorttitle='Strategy  ', overlay=true, default_qty_value=1000, initial_capital=1000, currency=currency.USD)
 
res1 = input(title='Time frame (Minutes. Not lower than chart)', defval='300')
mhshift = input(title='Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift', defval=0)
fama = input(title='Heikin Ashi EMA Period', defval=16)
test = input(title='Heikin Ashi EMA Shift', defval=0)
 
ha_t = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid) 
mha_close = request.security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift]) 

// Moving Average
fma = ta.ema(mha_close[test], fama)
// sma = ta.ema(ha_close[slomas], sloma)
plot(fma, title='MA', color=color.new(#e6bc00, 22), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
```

Is it possible to do the same with the chart result?

The captured chart shows different results. I would like to have the same result even if I upgrade the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of the `security` function has changed from v2 to v3. You can read about it in the [migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed).

To get the same result, you would need to add `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` which is off by default from v3 onward.

```
mha_close = request.security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

The reason behind this change is about the [lookahead](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html?#lookahead), which causes a [future leak](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#future-leak-with-request-security) on historical bars (in your case, it happens when your input `mhshift` is set to 0).

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript version 2 is depreacated.

If you change the version number to 3 (without other modification) you will see the same results.
The difference between V2 and V5 comes from

```
security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift]) in version 2
```

gives different results from

```
request.security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift])' in version 5
```

Comment: Changing to version 3 gives different results. I would like to have the same result even if I upgrade the version. Is there a way?